# Is it possible to inverse a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

this is probably not a task, but a question, now I'll explain what I want to ask.

So, backstory, there are the following input data:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO] incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimus veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure http://domains.ua/ dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu: fugiat: nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat: cupidatat [non] proident :,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est labor labor. https://foo.co.uk/ *end.
```

The task was to find all occurrences that are in square brackets, in this line: this is: `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO]` and `[non]`, then find all the links that begin with `http/https` and end with slash (`/`) followed by a space immediately. (correctness of references is not important)

In general, to find all these occurrences was easily, here is the regular expression ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxibvM/1)):

```
\[.*?\]|https?://[\w\.]+/\h
```

Is it possible to invert this regular expression so as to find everything except the conditions specified in the task? (do not highlight in square brackets and links)

Comment: Was it [this RU question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873261)? Note OP wants a solution in JavaScript, as far as I understand. In general, the best way to get all that is not matched with a regex is to use the regex to split the string.

Comment: you mean `explode`?

Comment: When dealing with a regex, `preg_split('~\[.*?]|https?://[\w.]+/\h~', $s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, indeed, I forgot all about her, thank you very much.

Comment: If you mean a logical negation of a regex that would usually mean practically everything, you probably mean what @WiktorStribiżew said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the help [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), think, i solved the issue the following way:

```
echo join('', preg_split('~\[.*?]|https?://[\w.]+/\h~', $string));
```

Comment: Come on, if you just wanted to remove the matched text, why bother with splitting? Use `preg_replace` directly.